# Activity has leaked window

Tags: android, android-activity, window

In my splash screen, I made it so that it detects whether wifi or 3g is enabled or not. If it is not, a dialog screen prompts the user to exit and turn either one on. If it is on, then the code will continue. I keep getting an error in my logcat about my activity having a leaked window. I am not sure how to solve this issue. Code and logcat below. Any Ideas?

Here's my code:

```
//create alert dialog for wifi and 3g
connectionDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashMain.this).create();
Log.d(TAG, "dialog created");
connectionDialog.setTitle("Wifi or 3G not detected. Please enable either Wifi or 3G");
connectionDialog.setButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
    }
});

wifiHandler = new Handler();
setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);  //Make the splash screen load first
Thread splashScreenTimer = new Thread(){ //create a timer for the splash screen
    public void run(){      //create a run class
        Looper.prepare();   //prepare looper
        try{            //methods within the run class
            int screenTimer =0;
            //make it last 3 seconds - create a while loop
            while(screenTimer <3000){
                sleep(100); //100= 1/10th of a second
                screenTimer = screenTimer +100;
            }
            connectionState();  //check wifi stuff
            Log.d(TAG, "checked wifi state");
            if(mobile == true || wifi == true){
                Log.d(TAG, "wifi is true");
                connectionDialog.dismiss();
                startActivity (new Intent("ravebox.dev.sdr.CLEARSCREEN"));
                finish();
                Log.d(TAG, "started activity");
            }
            if(mobile == false || wifi == false){
                Log.d(TAG, "wifi is false");
                wifiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "show dialog");
                        connectionDialog.show();
                        Log.d(TAG, "show'd dialog");
                    }
                });
            }//add activity to the manifest
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            //finish();
        }
    }
};
splashScreenTimer.start();
```

Log cat:

```
08-30 22:45:32.188: ERROR/WindowManager(334): Activity ravebox.dev.sdr.SplashMain has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405377e0 that was originally added here
08-30 22:45:32.188: ERROR/WindowManager(334): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity ravebox.dev.sdr.SplashMain has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405377e0 that was originally added here
08-30 22:45:32.188: ERROR/WindowManager(334):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:258)
08-30 22:45:32.188: ERROR/WindowManager(334):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
08-30 22:45:32.188: ERROR/WindowManager(334):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
08-30 22:45:32.188: ERROR/WindowManager(334):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:465)
08-30 22:45:32.188: ERROR/WindowManager(334):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
08-30 22:45:32.188: ERROR/WindowManager(334):     at ravebox.dev.sdr.SplashMain$2$1.run(SplashMain.java:90)
08-30 22:45:32.188: ERROR/WindowManager(334):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-30 22:45:32.188: ERROR/WindowManager(334):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-30 22:45:32.188: ERROR/WindowManager(334):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-30 22:45:32.188: ERROR/WindowManager(334):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
08-30 22:45:32.188: ERROR/WindowManager(334):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-30 22:45:32.188: ERROR/WindowManager(334):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-30 22:45:32.188: ERROR/WindowManager(334):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
08-30 22:45:32.188: ERROR/WindowManager(334):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
08-30 22:45:32.188: ERROR/WindowManager(334):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an answer that shows why this problem occurs: [Activity has leaked window that was originally added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added)

Now, in you case you have written this code

```
if(mobile == true || wifi == true){
      Log.d(TAG, "wifi is true");
      connectionDialog.dismiss();
      startActivity (new Intent("ravebox.dev.sdr.CLEARSCREEN"));
      finish();
      Log.d(TAG, "started activity");
}
```

In the above code where are you showing the `connectionDialog.dismiss();` before dismissing it.

And in this code you are showing the dialog by `connectionDialog.show();` but where is the code to dismiss it.

```
if(mobile == false || wifi == false){
      Log.d(TAG, "wifi is false");
      wifiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
         Log.d(TAG, "show dialog");
         connectionDialog.show();
         Log.d(TAG, "show'd dialog");
      }
});
```

So, please find a solution for this, it should be something like this.

Show the dialog in starting only, if the wifi is connected `cancel()` it and move to next activity, if not connected `cancel()` it after sometime and giving a message that wifi not found or connected.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is because you are updating the UI within the Thread. In particular, this block of code:

```
    if(mobile == true || wifi == true){
       Log.d(TAG, "wifi is true");
       connectionDialog.dismiss();
       startActivity (new Intent("ravebox.dev.sdr.CLEARSCREEN"));
       finish();
       Log.d(TAG, "started activity");
    }
```

As an alternative you might want to use [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) for counting down and check the above code at onFinish() method

Answer (score 1):

Solution one:
dismiss your `AlertDialog` before finish your Activity.

```
AlertDialog.dismiss();
```

Solution two:
Add the following field for your Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|navigation"
```

Comment: what the second method actually does ?

Answer (score 0):

find any code that may throws exceptions
i got the same exception when "url" is wrong like followings:

```
String url = String.format(SOAP_REGISTER_URL, serviceCenterAddress);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
```

just set the right url it runs