# Android Facebook authorize not working (leaked window)

Tags: android, facebook, memory-leaks

I have the similar problem as [Android Facebook.authorize don't call oncomplete method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8458004/898722)

onComplete method isn`t called after authorization in Facebook (both when Facebook app is installed or not).

Activity class

```
package com.greatapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.android.*;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.*;

public class MyGreatAppActivity extends Activity {

Facebook facebook = new Facebook("YOUR_APP_ID");

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    facebook.authorize(this, new Facebook.DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

As You see from code, i`ve implemented onActivityResult as it was shown in official guide http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/sso/

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.greatapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyGreatAppActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And there is no android:noHistory flag in manifest file.

The only error i've found in log

```
 Activity com.greatapp.MyGreatActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44e8c518 that was originally added here
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.greatapp.MyGreatActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44e8c518 that was originally added here
at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:227)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:239)
at com.facebook.android.Facebook.dialog(Facebook.java:814)
at com.facebook.android.Facebook.startDialogAuth(Facebook.java:343)
at com.facebook.android.Facebook.authorize(Facebook.java:206)
at com.facebook.android.Facebook.authorize(Facebook.java:114)
at com.greatapp.MyGreatActivity.onCreate(MyGreatActivity.java:18)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've tried android 2.1, 2.2 and 4.0.3 and have the same issue.

Copying classes from example from Facebook sdk also didn't work.

Please provide any possible help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Weird, that (usually) means that the activity was closed, you can read these threads: [Activity has leaked window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252086/activity-has-leaked-window) and [Activity has leaked window that was originally added](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue with the Facebook Android SSO, it even says so in the [Platform Status](http://developers.facebook.com/live_status/).

You can get more info at this bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/385350798163367

Comment: Actually i don`t get this error, there is no such record in logs. Android just stays on facebook page instead of returning to application.

Comment: You're code looks fine to me. How are you sure that the *onComplete* is not called? there's nothing in that method, or are you debugging? The bug report is for a specific one, but facebook writes in the platform status "We are working on a fix for the Android SSO errors" (notice the plural form), and so I think it's safe to assume that it might be somehow related. Are you running this with an emulator? If so, you can run a network sniffer and see what happens in the background.

Comment: Yep, i`m debugging on external device. I've figured out, that example that came with facebook android sdk has the same issue. I've found an error in logs and updated the question.